# Style defined in ResourceDictionary referencing a template within the same ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have created a ResourceDictionary in my WPF application like so:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfRibbonApplication1"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                xmlns:vsm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2007/xaml/presentation" >
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Inside of this resource dictionary I have defined a style for my custom textbox control like so:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SimpleSwingTextBox}" x:Key="SimpleSwingTextBoxStyle">
</style>
```

Within the style is a tooltip:

```
<ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" Template="{StaticResource ValidationToolTipTemplate}">
</Tooltip>
```

Also within the same ResourceDictionary I have the template referenced above in the style:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationToolTipTemplate">
</ControlTemplate>
```

Then in my C# code, I create an instance of my custom text box control and set its style to the style defined in the resource dictionary:

```
SimpleSwingTextBox textBox = new SimpleSwingTextBox(textPoint);

Uri resourceLocator = new Uri("Assets/SimpleSwingResourceDictionary.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);
ResourceDictionary rd = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(resourceLocator);
textBox.Style = rd["SimpleSwingTextBoxStyle"] as Style;
```

The problem I have is that an exception is immediately thrown which has the following message:

"Cannot find resource named 'ValidationToolTipTemplate'. Resource names are case sensitive."

I don't understand how the style I created cannot find the 'ValidationToolTipTemplate' when they are in the same ResourceDictionary xaml file?

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?  Thanks

Comment: Does ValidationToolTipTemplate created before validationTooltip?

Comment: Ok, I just moved 'ValidationToolTipTemplate' to be before the style references it in the file.  It works now.  Thanks Spawn!